# Validate an XML against XSD and send errors to a file?

Tags: xml, bash, xsd, xml-validation, xmllint

I need to validate an XML against an XSD, I am using `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --schema schema.xsd feed.xml --noout
```

But it seems that I cannot save the output of the validation to a file.

Using `-o` or `--output` or `>` to redirect the output to a file will output the parse XML, but how do I redirect the validation errors to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect `stderr` in general via `2>`, so

```
xmllint --schema try.xsd try.xml --noout 2>errors.txt
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

will redirect the errors to `errors.txt`.